# ONE FREE item from Category 'X' so long as the Customer orders a MINIMUM amount

Tags: cart, rules, shopping

I would like to be able to give a ONE FREE item from Category 'X' so long as the Customer orders a MINIMUM amount of say $30.

How to do this?

Thanks!